# Segmented Control with ViewControllers MFMailComposer rotation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I've a ViewController which Contains a segmented Control.

Each Segmented Control has his own View Controller. Technically I initiate a ViewController for each Segmented Control and display the View to display, and hide the other views.

This works all good, but now I tried to display a MFMailComposer with presentModalViewController. That I clearly need to do on the ViewController where the Segmented Control is on it, because from the other ViewControllers I only put the view above the segmented Control.

The MFMailComposer appears and disappears, but after disappearing the complete App rotated 180°. I only support one Orientation, the 180° rotation isn't supported by the plist.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the Function: `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` in my TabBar Controller. Now I removed that and now it's fixed.